# ESLint warning event is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, undefined, eslint

I'm getting an error with ESLint on this simple bit of code:

```
var trigger = document.getElementById("hello");
var audio = new Audio('audio/hello.mp3');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    trigger.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        audio.play();
    }, false);
});
```

The error I'm getting is: `'event' is defined but never used.`

I've read that I can disable this error by adding a comment after the open brace where 'event' is used like this: `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars`.

But my question is, is anything actually wrong with this code and should it be fixed or improved on? Rather than covered up by a comment ignoring the warning? Or is there actually nothing wrong with this approach and it's just ESLint being pedantic?

Comment: _"is anything actually wrong with this code and should it be fixed or improved on?"_ - ESLint tells you exactly what the "problem" is... You're never using the `event` in `.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {`

Comment: Yes but every answer on here is pretty much people saying to comment it out

Comment: It's your script. Your ESLint config. Do whatever you think is correct. Anything else is an opinion from an internet stranger. The objected parameter is unnecessary so just get rid of it as @T.J.Crowder explained in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my question is, is anything actually wrong with this code and should it be fixed or improved on?

You're never using the `event` parameter you define in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener (you're only using the one defined in the `click` handler), so you should remove it:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// No `event` here −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

---

Having said that, though, using `DOMContentLoaded` is unnecessary **if** you control the `script` tag that loads the code. If you do, just use `type="module"` or `defer` to ensure the code doesn't run until the DOM is built.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have this addEventListener at first but it actually stopped script running that followed it so why I needed to include it in the end!

Comment: Know it was a bit of a noob question and I feel a bit silly now but I didn't know I could leave that empty. But little things like this help me a lot going forward and trying to understand JS - thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Linters can be annoying, but it’s usually a good idea to try and keep them happy. Instead of disabling the warning, though, you can indicate that you are deliberately ignoring a parameter by beginning its name with an underscore.

```
var trigger = document.getElementById("hello");
var audio = new Audio('audio/hello.mp3');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (_event) => {
    trigger.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        audio.play();
    }, false);
});
```

You can also use just an underscore for the parameter name, or leave it out completely.